# Writing a function about a virtual set of playing cards that quantifies to 52 cards

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried various codes to no avail. I am looking for an effective approach to solving this problem. I will provide codes below that I have tried. I think the notion of random sample plays some role in the code, but not sure what that role is.

I have tried the following code. In my experience, I do not think "class" works to answer this problem, but I admit, it may be functional, it just does not have the efficacy I am looking for. I am not sure if or for loops are required but maybe they are. I am stuck.

```
class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs']
        self.values = range(1,14)
        self.ActualCards = [] #Empty List to Append
        for Card in itertools.product(self.suits,self.values):
            self.ActualCards.append(Card) #Cartesian Product to Create Deck
```

Here are the instructions: Write a function poker(num_cards) that draws num_cards cards at random from a standard 52-card deck of playing cards. You're free to come up with your own abbreviations for the different suits and cards, if you would prefer. The output should be a list containing the requested number of cards, chosen at random from the full deck. Each card should be its own string. For example, print(poker(2)) returns a list of two random cards, which can be ['C2', 'H3'], or ['S6', 'C12'] etc.. (When replying, please test it to ensure that it spits out what it should, e.g. print(poker(2)) returns a list of 2 random cards, which can be ['C2', 'H3'], or ['S6', 'C12'] to note: we are given the following hint that I would like to incorporate if it were possible to do so:

Club = C, Diamond = D, Heart = H, Spade = S (Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13)

(Before answering, please test it to ensure accuracy, e.g. print(poker(2)) returns a list of two random cards, which can be ['C2', 'H3'], or ['S6', 'C12']

Comment: Take a look at [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: `random.sample(self.ActualCards, 2)` will literally return two cards picked at random. You just need to get your cards in a nicer shape.

Comment: Currently your cards are tuples like `('Clubs', 11)`. There are two ways you could go about it, depending on whether you need values' numeric value, and suits' full names, or not. The "better" way is to have a class `Card` that does a lot of heavy lifting. The easier way is much easier. Is there anything you can do about `self.suits` to get `('C', 11)` instead of `('Clubs', 11)`? And if I give you a hint that `for Card in...` can also be written as `for suit, value in...`, is there anything you could do to get `'C11'` instead of `('C', 11)`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest:

```
import random

SUITS = ['S','H','D','C']
VALUES = range(1,14)

def poker(k):
    cards = [suit + str(value) for suit in SUITS for value in VALUES]
    return random.sample(cards, k)
```

Comment: Are you capable as well of answering this question: Create a version of poker that allows you to generate up to four hands with as many as seven cards per hand where the same card cannot appear in multiple hands. Have Python return a list containing {# hands} elements, where each element is a list containing {# cards}. For example, print(poker2(7,2)) returns a list of list, which can be [['D13', 'D9', 'H5', 'H7', 'H8', 'S1', 'S9'], ['C11', 'C12', 'D11', 'D3', 'H10', 'H4', 'S12']] etc..

Comment: Sure I am. However, and excuse my bluntness but... are you learning anything this way? You got a friend to answer part of your assignment, then an internet stranger to polish it up, without understanding any of it. Anyway, here you go: `def poker2(k, p): d = poker(k * p); return [d[x:x+k] for x in range(0, k * p, k)]`

Comment: Different people learn differently, so YMMV. My first recommendation: go through [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), and practice everything you read. At the same time, practice decomposing problems. How do you ride a bus? Normal person: "I just do". Programmer: "approach the station (assuming you know how to walk). while there is no bus (assuming you know how to recognise a bus), wait and observe the road. while the door is closed: wait. ascend steps. pay driver. if overpaid, while haven't received change, wait. filter seats for empty; if any such, pick one and sit. etc.."

Comment: Tutorial _is_ a shortcut (the full deal is Python [language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) and [library](https://docs.python.org/3//library/index.html) reference). No, my knowledge is not all from tutorial, I actually never read it. I did read a large part of the language reference, and a lot of code. Practice, practice, practice.